# How to get records from table that depends on another tables in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to get some records from Database that depends on three tables.
Three tables are:

```
1.Company(Id,Name)
2. Car(Id,CompanyId,Name)
3. Showroom(Id,CarId,Name)
```

Now a one company contains many cars and many cars may exist in many showrooms.
I want to get records from showroom table where company '2' cars exist along with cars. Is it possible to do it in entity framework core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your entities will be like :

**Company**

```
 public class Company
 {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Car> Cars {get; set;}
  }
```

**Car:**

```
public class Car
   {
        public int Id{get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int CompanyId{get; set;}
        public Company Company {get; set;}

      }
```

**ShowRoom:**

```
public class ShowRoom
     {
        public int Id{get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public int CarId{get; set;}
        public Car Car{get; set;}

      }
```

**In your method:**

```
var context = new SomeContext();



 var showRooms= context.ShowRooms
                    .Include(x=> x.Car)
                    .ThenInclude(x=> x.Company)
                    .Where(x=> x.Car.Company.Id== 2)
                    .ToList();
```